# How to deploy android application to a device?

Tags: android, deployment

I developed an application. Now I want to deploy it on real device. Can any body please tell me the steps and the requirements to deploy it on a real device.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

1. If you don't use eclipse, you can use adb tool. `adb -d install PATH_TO_YOUR_APK_FILE`
2. If you use eclipse, you can click run application in eclipse's launch menu. If this doesn't work, make sure you have "USB Debugging Mode" checked on your android phone. It's in the application menu.
3. You can export your package and sign it! And then browse to it to install.

Answer (score 18):

I just copy the APK for my project out of the /workspace/project/bin folder, and use Dropbox to send it to my device.  Then I install the APK from Dropbox client on the device. (No need for cables!)

Comment: could always just email the APK to yourself if you don't want to bother going through dropbox

Comment: ADB supports debugging over wifi now, so you can just enable that and use a single command to install and run your app wirelessly. Much faster than emailing it to yourself or dropbox.

Answer (score 17):

Hook up your SmartPhone through USB-cable and set your phone i debug mode found in `Settings > Applications > Development > USB debugging`. Next - run your project in eclipse and chose your device.

make sure 'Run configurations' is set to manual, or this will fail if set to automatic and the target is a emulator. To change this behaviour, go to 'Run > Run configurations > Target' and set 'Deployment Target Selection Mode' to manual. Click 'Close' and try again.

Comment: For my HTC Evo V, it's a little different (this answer is a couple years old). Settings => Developer options => Check "USB debugging"

Comment: On some devices, the USB cable must be disconnected to allow the `USB debugging` checkbox to be checked (e.g. LG G2)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you're on a Galaxy Nexus, you need to fish around Samsung's website to find the driver installer. Here it is : http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I515MSAVZW

Note: If you're using  **adb -d install PATH_TO_YOUR_APK_FILE** to install the apk on to your device,
you will need to run it from the adt-bundle-[magic]/sdk/platform-tools/ folder.

Better yet, add **adb.exe** to your $PATH, and you can run adb from your windows command line/ terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you have to set up your system to detect your device.

- If you're developing on Windows, you need to install a USB driver for adb. For an installation guide and links to OEM drivers, see the [OEM USB Drivers document](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html).
- If you're developing on Mac OS X, it just works. Skip this step.
- If you're developing on Linux see official Android guide [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)