# Android test application directly on device

Tags: android, testing, device

is there a way to compile an apk and test it directly in an usb-attached device ? The emulator is way too slow for a fluid development.

Comment: What do you mean by "test it"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deploy android application to a device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414424/how-to-deploy-android-application-to-a-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using eclipse, make sure the project is debuggable, software for the phone is installed on the computer. Set the phone to accept unknown recourses. First connect the phone, then start eclipse (sometimes the other way round results in the phone not being found) If you try to run the application eclipse should prompt you asking witch device to use. Click your phone and presto!