# Connect PC to Phone

Tags: android

I want to know how to connect my PC to phone.I'm doing an Android Programme and want to run it on my phone.How should I "build and run" it in from the android-eclipse to my samsung P500 phone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android test application directly on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957066/android-test-application-directly-on-device)

Comment: thank you to all!!!i successfully connected to phone...

Comment: np glad we could help :) one of those really anoing thing about being Android developer, USB Drivers for every single phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no samsung p500 as far as I know... do you mean LG p500?

Edit: Okay so you got an LG P500, well too bad you have to go through hell (just kidding). You can do multiple things to make it work, but first try to go to LG and use their usb driver download.
Link for guide to instal:

http://forums.androidcentral.com/other-android-phones/42678-how-install-usb-drivers-lg-optimus-one.html

If that doesn't completely solve it try going to (on windows 7) go to my computer -> right click go to manage -> device manager tab -> find your android device (will have yellow marker indicating some kind of problem) and right click it and find update drivers.

Comment: Not downvoting. This can be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice guide which illustrates how to do so: [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Comment: yes..i gone thru those documents...not getting what the step 4 says about to install USB drivers.please help

Comment: Be more specific on what you don't understand. It's clear to me.