# How to deploy to CyanogenMod Android tablet?

Tags: android, netbeans, deployment, cyanogenmod, touchpad

**How do i deploy an NBAndroid app (by directly moving the .apk file or else compiling straight from NetBeans?) onto a connected tablet (HP Touch that i just put CyanogenMod ICS onto)?** I connect it to my computer and it isnt recognised (like WebOS was) but Android ICS was installed fine. Do i need to use the bootloader to do this? I had a quick google and Stack search but could only see stuff relevant to using the emulator, and thought id probably get an answer here quicker.

Edit: this is the same question as this [How to deploy android application to a device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414424/how-to-deploy-android-application-to-a-device) which i discovered afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found how to connect to a device via here 
[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)
using this method you can get the .apk on the device without using dropbox
But the dropbox method is easier, even in development.

Answer (score 1):

If the Tablet is not recogniced (have this problem at work, too, even with stock OS) maybe give it a try syncing it via a dropbox folder. Its the best bet for me, so far.

Comment: you beat me to it. i just did this myself before reading your comment. Dropbox just works.

Comment: possibly it doesnt have a manager/driver on it yet for my mac to recognise it as a volume, or to be able to transfer files to/fro? it does recognise its plugged in, but thats all from what i can tell. Im new to this ROM installation.

Comment: To be honest - I never tried any ROM stuff yet. And it's the first time I hear some device is not recogniced by a mac correctly. Maybe try switching between USB connection modes? On my mac at home I have no problem, but at work those stupi wim machines don't recognise my tablet at all :D

Comment: although the dropbox method answered my question, i was looking for how to directly connect to the device over usb. thanks for your help though.